# Terraform lambda source_code_hash from S3 data doesn't stick in the state cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, hash, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform configuration for allocating an AWS Lambda.  I want it to automatically update the code when it detects a change.  To do this, I'm using the `source_code_hash` property, as you can see below. As part of my build process I zip all the code up and then use `openssl` to get an SHA256 hash of the zip file, stick it in a text file, and then upload both to an S3 bucket.

Here is my Terraform configuration:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "mylambdacode_sha256" {
  bucket = "myapp-builds"
  key    = "build.zip.sha256"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {

  function_name = "${var.lambda_function_name}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler = "index.handler"

  runtime = "nodejs10.x"

  s3_bucket = "myapp-builds"
  s3_key = "build.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.mylambdacode_sha256.body}"

  timeout = 900

}
```

I run `terraform apply` and it shows me that the `source_code_hash` has changed:

```
 ~ source_code_hash               = <<~EOT
          - c9Nl4RRfuh/Z5fJvEOT69GDTJqY9n/QTB5cBGtOniYc=
          + 73d365e1145fba1fd9e5f26f10e4faf460d326a63d9ff4130797011ad3a78987
```

The `73d365e1145fba1fd9e5f26f10e4faf460d326a63d9ff4130797011ad3a78987` part is indeed what's in the file on S3.  So, this all looks right. But then when I run `terraform apply` again immediately afterwards it thinks the hash has changed again.

Checking the `.tfstate` file I see that the hash it just said was new is not being saved.

Is Terraform hashing my hash or doing some other manipulation and saving the result of that to `.tfstate`?  Or do I have something configured incorrectly?

EDIT:

Per the answer below I've updated the `source_code_hash` statement to use the `base64encode` function as follows:

```
source_code_hash = "${base64encode(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.my_lambda_build_sha256.body)}"
```

Here is the output from `terraform state show aws_lambda_function.my_lambda && terraform apply && terraform state show aws_lambda_function.my_lambda`

```
$ terraform state show aws_lambda_function.my_lambda && terraform apply && terraform state show aws_lambda_function.my_lambda
# aws_lambda_function.my_lambda:
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
    arn                            = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda"
    function_name                  = "my_lambda"
    handler                        = "index.handler"
    id                             = "my_lambda"
    invoke_arn                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda/invocations"
    last_modified                  = "2019-08-02T15:00:32.621+0000"
    layers                         = []
    memory_size                    = 128
    publish                        = false
    qualified_arn                  = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda:$LATEST"
    reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
    role                           = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/my_lambda-role"
    runtime                        = "nodejs10.x"
    s3_bucket                      = "myapp-builds"
    s3_key                         = "myapp/build.zip"
    source_code_hash               = "r5D6o1FuCug6FD4QPQ43VdUlfYP4Qe1l1DcElNsf5E0="
    source_code_size               = 12793672
    tags                           = {}
    timeout                        = 900
    version                        = "$LATEST"

    tracing_config {
        mode = "PassThrough"
    }
}
postgresql_database.postgres: Refreshing state... [id=postgres]
aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:policy/lambda_logging]
aws_cloudwatch_log_group.my_lambda: Refreshing state... [id=/aws/lambda/my_lambda]
aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda: Refreshing state... [id=my_lambda-role]
aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.my_lambda-rule: Refreshing state... [id=my_lambda-rule]
data.aws_s3_bucket_object.myapp_lambda_build_sha256: Refreshing state...
data.aws_s3_bucket_object.myapp_lambda_build_zip: Refreshing state...
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.lambda_logs: Refreshing state... [id=my_lambda-role-20190801190935907200000001]
aws_lambda_function.my_lambda: Refreshing state... [id=my_lambda]
aws_lambda_permission.allow_cloudwatch_to_call_trigger_lambda: Refreshing state... [id=AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch]
aws_cloudwatch_event_target.my_lambda-rule-event-target: Refreshing state... [id=my_lambda-rule-terraform-20190801192030362600000001]

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_lambda_function.my_lambda will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
        arn                            = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda"
        function_name                  = "my_lambda"
        handler                        = "index.handler"
        id                             = "my_lambda"
        invoke_arn                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda/invocations"
      ~ last_modified                  = "2019-08-02T15:00:32.621+0000" -> (known after apply)
        layers                         = []
        memory_size                    = 128
        publish                        = false
        qualified_arn                  = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda:$LATEST"
        reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
        role                           = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/my_lambda-role"
        runtime                        = "nodejs10.x"
        s3_bucket                      = "myapp-builds"
        s3_key                         = "myapp/build.zip"
      ~ source_code_hash               = "r5D6o1FuCug6FD4QPQ43VdUlfYP4Qe1l1DcElNsf5E0=" -> "YWY5MGZhYTM1MTZlMGFlODNhMTQzZTEwM2QwZTM3NTVkNTI1N2Q4M2Y4NDFlZDY1ZDQzNzA0OTRkYjFmZTQ0ZAo="
        source_code_size               = 12793672
        tags                           = {}
        timeout                        = 900
        version                        = "$LATEST"

        tracing_config {
            mode = "PassThrough"
        }
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_lambda_function.my_lambda: Modifying... [id=my_lambda]
aws_lambda_function.my_lambda: Modifications complete after 1s [id=my_lambda]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.
# aws_lambda_function.my_lambda:
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
    arn                            = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda"
    function_name                  = "my_lambda"
    handler                        = "index.handler"
    id                             = "my_lambda"
    invoke_arn                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda/invocations"
    last_modified                  = "2019-08-02T15:05:08.079+0000"
    layers                         = []
    memory_size                    = 128
    publish                        = false
    qualified_arn                  = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:my_lambda:$LATEST"
    reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
    role                           = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/my_lambda-role"
    runtime                        = "nodejs10.x"
    s3_bucket                      = "myapp-builds"
    s3_key                         = "myapp/build.zip"
    source_code_hash               = "r5D6o1FuCug6FD4QPQ43VdUlfYP4Qe1l1DcElNsf5E0="
    source_code_size               = 12793672
    tags                           = {}
    timeout                        = 900
    version                        = "$LATEST"

    tracing_config {
        mode = "PassThrough"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `terraform state show aws_lambda_function.my_lambda && terraform apply && terraform state show aws_lambda_function.my_lambda` please?

Answer (score 8):

It works for me generating the "build.zip.sha256" before upload it to S3 with:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary build.zip | openssl enc -base64 > build.zip.sha256
```

To avoid <<~EOT mismatch with the original sha256 I use:

```
source_code_hash = chomp(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.my_lambda_build_sha256.body)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it solved the issue for me.

Comment: This! THIS! Thank you for saving me from wasting more hours.