# Terraform lambda source_code_hash from S3 object timestamp doesn't get updated in the state cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**Background**:

I have a Terraform configuration for allocating an AWS Lambda. I want it to automatically update the code when it detects a change. To do this, I'm using the source_code_hash property, as you can see below.

As part of my build process I zip all the source code and upload it to an S3 bucket.

I use the last modified time of the S3 object to trigger the build to redeploy changes.

**Problem**:

When I deploy the change, the `source_code_hash` attribute is never updated. In the terraform plan it states that it will update the value to be `b0IwKd/Fk38A+R20lGIWwCWP6p9UKmAmwns0it2J4qA=`, but it always gets set to `b2+fXCsSQrxTJq5RonkDz8KhyOt8ICJYZGSsHkygrvY=`.

**Similar questions**:

- The following questions are similar to mine but they don't address my issue:

  - [Terraform lambda source_code_hash update with same code]([Terraform lambda source_code_hash update with same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662244/terraform-lambda-source-code-hash-update-with-same-code%5C))
  - [Terraform lambda source_code_hash from S3 data doesn't stick in the state cache]([Terraform lambda source_code_hash from S3 data doesn't stick in the state cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317157/terraform-lambda-source-code-hash-from-s3-data-doesnt-stick-in-the-state-cache%5C))

**Terraform configuration**:

```
data "aws_s3_object" "this" {
  bucket = var.s3_bucket
  key    = var.s3_key
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  s3_bucket        = var.s3_bucket
  s3_key           = var.s3_key
  source_code_hash = base64sha256(data.aws_s3_object.this.last_modified)
  ...
}
```

**Terraform apply output first run**:

```
# aws_lambda_function.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
      ~ source_code_hash               = "b2+fXCsSQrxTJq5RonkDz8KhyOt8ICJYZGSsHkygrvY=" -> "b0IwKd/Fk38A+R20lGIWwCWP6p9UKmAmwns0it2J4qA="
      ...
    }
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

**Terraform apply output second run**:

```
# aws_lambda_function.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
      ~ source_code_hash               = "b2+fXCsSQrxTJq5RonkDz8KhyOt8ICJYZGSsHkygrvY=" -> "b0IwKd/Fk38A+R20lGIWwCWP6p9UKmAmwns0it2J4qA="
      ...
    }
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I tried to set source code hash to the following values:

- `source_code_hash = base64encode(sha256(data.aws_s3_object.this.last_modified))`
- `source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(data.aws_s3_object.this.last_modified)}"`
- `source_code_hash = base64sha256("${data.aws_s3_object.this.last_modified}")`
- `source_code_hash = base64sha256("Wed, 15 Mar 2023 21:08:25 GMT")`

I think the problem is how the `source_code_hash` gets stored internally in the Terraform state.

I set base64sha256 to a default value and I'm experiencing the same issue.

## Solution

I ended up uploading a sha256.txt file to the S3 bucket and used that instead.

I followed Naxest answer in [Terraform lambda source_code_hash from S3 data doesn't stick in the state cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317157/terraform-lambda-source-code-hash-from-s3-data-doesnt-stick-in-the-state-cache)

Make sure you save your file with the `.txt` extension or else `data.aws_s3_object.this.body` will return null. See Note in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_object for more info on the body field.

Comment: Can you try with `etag`: `data.aws_s3_object.this.etag`?